# Generate English words using special characters in the comments

Tags: comments, documentation

I want to generate a English word with pure characters like `|`, `/`, `\`, `(`, `)` etc. in my code comments.
For example,

```
                                _
                               (_)
 __   __   __ _    ___    ___   _ 
 \ \ / /  / _` |  / __|  / __| | |
  \ V /  | (_| | | (__  | (__  | |
   \_/    \__,_|  \___|  \___| |_|
```

I wonder if there is a tool that automatically does the job? I don't know how to properly google it.

Comment: I'd search for "ascii art text".

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That's what I'm looking for! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tool might be helpful: https://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&h=1&v=1&f=Big&t=vaccine

You can choose your favorite font, character width/height, and copy the wonderful ASCII art to your clipboard.